# MetisMenu with Angular 2 two-way-binding refreshes after model is updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am using a metisMenu, with Angular 2 two-way-binding to a model. My model is a house object, which has a collection of floors; the floors have rooms, and the rooms have items. The entire house tree is reflected in my metisMenu.

The problem is that when I update my model by adding a new object to a collection - for example, I add a new room - when I click this new object added in the menu, the page refreshes (the normal behavior would be to expand the section and display its children). I don't know why this happens and I would like to prevent it, somehow. But I have no idea how.

Any hints are very much welcomed.

Comment: can you please post your code as well

Comment: can you provide a working jsfiddle?